# how to organize the array alements in a better way

Tags: javascript

I have array something like, which will have many more elements. Is there a better/compact way to orgnize this?

```
var codes= new Array();
    codes['a']=0x0627;
    codes['b']=0x0628;
    codes['c']=0x0686;
    codes['d']=0x062F;
    codes['e']=0x0639;
    codes['f']=0x0641;
    codes['g']=0x06AF;
    codes['h']=0x06BE;
    codes['i']=0x06CC;
    codes['j']=0x062C;
    codes['k']=0x06A9;
    codes['l']=0x0644;
    codes['m']=0x0645;
    codes['n']=0x0646;
    codes['o']=0x06C1;
    codes['p']=0x067E;
    codes['q']=0x0642;
    codes['r']=0x0631;
    codes['s']=0x0633;
    codes['t']=0x062A;
    codes['u']=0x0626; 
    codes['v']=0x0637;
    codes['w']=0x0648;
    codes['x']=0x0634;
    codes['y']=0x06D2;
    codes['z']=0x0632;

    codes['A']=0x0622;
    codes['B']=0x0628;
    codes['C']=0x062B;
    codes['D']=0x0688;
    codes['E']=0x0651; 
    codes['F']=0x064D; 
    codes['G']=0x063A;
    codes['H']=0x062D;
    codes['I']=0x0670; 
    codes['J']=0x0636;
    codes['K']=0x062E;
    codes['L']=0x0628;
    codes['M']=0x064B; 
    codes['N']=0x06BA;
    codes['O']=0x0628;
    codes['P']=0x064F; 
    codes['Q']=0x0628;
    codes['R']=0x0691;
    codes['S']=0x0635;
    codes['T']=0x0679;
    codes['U']=0x0621;
    codes['V']=0x0638;
    codes['W']=0x0624;
    codes['X']=0x0698;
    codes['Z']=0x0630;

    codes['>']=0x0650; 
    codes['<']=0x064E;
```

Comment: That's an object, not an array. Look up "object literals".

Comment: You are confusing JavaScript with  PHP. In JavaScript your array elements have to be numberic. You can add properties to any object with myobject.myproperty=.. or myobject[myproperty]=... but you don't need an array for that.

Comment: Hint: `var codes = {a:0x0627, b:0x0628, ...}`.

Comment: In addition to @lonesomeday's comment, you don't want to use `new Array()`. You want to use `[]` for arrays or, in your case, `{}` for objects.

Comment: Why not just write a function to do the math?

Comment: There is no correlation between the letter index in the alphabet and the hexa value, no way to compute it automatically ?

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript parser is having to go through every single one of those commands, and create a new object property for each one. Believe me, I once tried to build an array this way (when I was just starting in JavaScript) and it took 30+ seconds just to load an array of 1,000 elements.

Instead, just construct your object:

```
var codes = {
    a: 0x0627,
    b: 0x0628,
    .......
};
```

This is a single statement, so it will run a hell of a lot faster.